# All the partitions on my hard disk have been removed. What can I do?

Tags: hard-drive

The problem begins here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/118224/i-have-big-problem-with-mount-partition

I tried to solve the problem by myself, but I messed up. I opened gparted magic and opened my hard disk and chose **Create Partition Table** and the disaster was done.

All the partitions on my hard disk (500 GB) have been removed. What can I do? I tried to use PTDD Partition Table Doctor 3.5, but it didn't help.

This drive had important data that I need to get back.

---

### Solution

Thanks for everyone who helped me and Allah help me to reach to solve this problem i will write it for your benefit.

The solution is after the problem happened and I lost all partitions.

**First**: You must leave your hard disk alone. Don't make any changes, like create new partition or move to it new data, no! You must leave it without any changes!

**Second**: You must you use any program to recover your partitions. I used alot of one but the very good one is the program: **[MiniTool Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)** It's free and good.

And in less than one minute my all hard disc return and thanks for all help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you have additional hard drive at hand, because you will use it to store rescued data. Ideally it should be the size or approximate of HD you are trying to save, unless you know beforehand the ammount of data you will rescue from it, in which case provide that capacity.

Download rescue CD, I would recommend [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=downloads), then boot it from CD or USB, whichever you opted to create.

Insert additional HD (if it's not external or SATA, connect it before turning the power on, of course), then mount both hard disks in Parted Magic.

There are two options from here and both involve using programs TestDisk and PhotoRec. They are made by same author and it is very advisable to familiarize yourself with their usage by going to [official webpage](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Option number one, which you should go through anyway, is to rescue data to second hard drive you provided trying first [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Undelete_files_from_NTFS_with_TestDisk) then [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) if needed. You could also make entire copy of your main HD using terminal command `dd`, and then work on that image, but it would require more space than mentioned solution and is not really necessary in this case (from what I understood your hard drive is not failing), but only if you carefully study and use recovery programs.

After you have your data stored safely on your additional drive, you can unmount and remove it. Then comes option number two, which you could come to in the first place but it is absolutely not advisable to skip previously described step (option number one). Now you can try to [recover your lost partition and even repair boot sector using TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step). If that fails for any reason, you would still have all your important data saved on second drive, assuming you didn't skip and thoroughly covered step one.

Comment: thanks man and i know that must be have additional hard disk

Answer (score 1):

Recover from a backup. That's what they're for.

Comment: of course i didn't backup because this is only bigger  mine harddisk

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said it had important data on it.